# How to use CACLS in c# windows service

Tags: c#, .net, service, c#-2.0, cacls

i want to block certain folder from users, using c# service. that means when you are starting the service though it is blocked or not, the final result is blocked folder. i have writen a code. but the responce is **are you sure?** please help to solve this

```
string Pathname = folder;
EventLog.WriteEntry(Pathname);
string Username = @"BUILTIN\Users";
string UserRights = "N";

if (Pathname == null || Pathname == "")
{
    EventLog.WriteEntry("No File");
}

string CommandLine = '"' + System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Pathname) + '"' + " /C ";
CommandLine += @" /T ";
CommandLine += @" /P " + Username + ":" + UserRights;

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cacls.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = CommandLine;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

p.Start();

string Response = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
EventLog.WriteEntry(Response);
if (Response == null || Response == "")
{
    EventLog.WriteEntry("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting the standard input for the CACLS process.
So you need to feed the process with your input (Like a stream.Writeline("Y");)
Look at this [sample from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx)

```
StreamWriter myStreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput;
myStreamWriter.Writeline("Y"); // Could it be localized ??? -->Oui, Ja, Sì etc...
myStreamWriter.Close();  // This seems to be is important.....
```

Comment: i tried p.StandardInput.WriteLine("Y"); and your method, both wont work

Answer (score 6):

Don't call the command line `cacls` utility, instead use the .NET API to change permissions. Invoking command line utilities should always be seen as a last workaround for performing tasks. It is much better to access an API directly that is meant for programmatic access.

- `Directory.GetAccessControl(string)` gets the current ACL.
- `Directory.SetAccessControl(string, DirectorySecurity)` sets the ACL.

Generally when working with ACLs it's better to work only with granting rights and not use deny flags at all. Denying `BUILTIN\Users` is very broad and that deny will overrule *any grant made to any* user. It is better to construct an ACL that does not grant any rights to normal users and only give rights to the specific users that should have access.